# Using trigger to change property of many items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I created a WPF custom control, which works fine.
It has a style which sets some properties and a template.

Now i want to change the control, so it has a 'Active' property.
If this is true it should use the Property 'ActiveBrush' for the Stroke
of some Rectangles in the Template, else it should use 'InactiveBrush'.

I want to use the ActiveBrush as the default Stroke, and change it to InactiveBrush
with a Trigger.

This works fine with one Rectangle when i use this:

```
<Trigger Property="Active" Value="False">
  <Setter TargetName="Rec1" Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding Path=InactiveBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

But since I don't want to set each rectangle with a seperated setter, I am asking myself if it shouldn't be possible to set the property of all Rectangles in the Template with one Setter.

I already tried:

```
<Trigger Property="Active" Value="False">
  <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="{Binding Path=InactiveBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

But this didn't work.

Has anyone a suggestion, how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Robert Rossney - this style will not run since a target type of Rectangle doesn't have a property Active. But that is the right path to go, with a minor change:

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding Path=InactiveBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This style should be nested in Style.Resources of the control style or in ControlTemplate.Resources of the ControlTemplate for the control. This way you're localizing this style only to your control. Any Rectangle outside of your control will not be affected.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. No errors, just not changing the Stroke.

Comment: The problem was: The default Stroke which I set with 'Stroke="..."' is overriding the value set by the style. By adding 2 DataTrigger (Active/Inactive) to the Style and leaving the default value unset, it works. But also only with x:Key in the Style and Style=... in the Rectangle.

Comment: @Marks - you raise a good point about precedence of setting a value to a Dependency Property. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) should be a good reference (have some problems loading the page right now to verify it). To make the code more readable, instead of the trigger for `Active=true` you can set it in a setter of the style and the trigger for `Active=false` will over-power it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you know this but are just overlooking it:  If you want to apply a style to all controls of a type, create a style with a `TargetType` of that type and put it in your custom control's resource dictionary.  If you still need to apply specific styles to individual controls of that type, define those styles using the `BasedOn` property.

So, in your `MyControl.Resources` element, you'd put:

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Active" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding Path=InactiveBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
      </Trigger>
   <Style>
<Style>
```

and any `Rectangle` that needed its own style would start like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Rectangle}}">
```